# exec osascript(AppleScript) from within NodeJS

Tags: browser, node.js, applescript, exec, osascript

I know I am probably missing this hugely,

but anyone knows why this keeps returning an error?

```
$ node -v && node
v0.4.6
> var cmd = 'osascript -e "open location \"http://google.com\""';
> require('child_process').exec(cmd, function (error, stdout, stderr) { console.log(error); });

//Error message
> { 
    stack: [Getter/Setter],
    arguments: undefined,
    type: undefined,
    message: 'Command failed: 15:20: syntax error: A “:” can’t go after this identifier. (-2740)\n',
    killed: false,
    code: 1,
    signal: null 
}
```

Perhaps it has something to do with the double quotes in the `cmd`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably just a quoting issue. This one works for me:

```
$ node -v && node
v0.4.8
> var cmd = 'osascript -e \'open location \"http://google.com\"\'';
> require('child_process').exec(cmd, function (error, stdout, stderr) { console.log(error); });
```

Btw, if you just want to open a URL, there is no need to go through AppleScript. Just use the [open](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html) command:

```
> var cmd = 'open \"http://google.com\"';
```

Comment: thanks a lot @sakra that worked very well :) also cheers to the tip saying that no applescript was necessary...yes I really needed to open an url on the default browser. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

This is simplified through backticks in current node version

```
$ node -v && node
v10.5.0
> let cmd = `osascript -e 'open location "http://google.com"'`
> require('child_process').exec(cmd, function (error, stdout, stderr) { console.log(error) })
```

and for the open command

```
var cmd = `open "http://google.com"`
```